# how to I add a class to an element created with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a class to a div I create with javascript. I could append it inside another div with a class. This is the line of code in question.

```
  var car_storage = document.createElement('div');
```

I have tried using, the code below, but I get instead of a class this, "is[object, object]"

```
  var car_storage = document.createElement('div'{className: 'car_storage_cont'});
```

Please help.

Comment: `car_storage.classList.add('className')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `className` property. It is a string and you need to concatenate to it the new class's name.

```
car_storage .className += ' car_storage_cont';
```

Comment: This is a very basic question and must have been answered many times. Please mark it duplicate

Comment: @Divern Please check dupes as they show more than 1 way with their benefits

Comment: @Rajesh, yeah, I just noticed that. My apologies. I am just new to javascript and didn't even know how it was called.

Comment: @Divern No need to apologies. We all are here to learn. Also, if refer to dupes and *accept/reject* based on merit so that no one else answers this question